# Execute a block of commands without keeping it in shell history (zsh)

Tags: zsh

I know you can avoid keeping the command in history if you use `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE`. But what about a block of commands?

Imagine I write something like:

```
nohistorystart
...cmds...
nohistoryend
```

Or something that starts a prompt.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/6141/77539), you can push/pop a new history, not associated with a save file.  (Note the capitals.)

```
fc -p 
...cmds...
fc -P
```

Answer (score 3):

Use a compound command beginning with a space.

```
%  {
cursh> echo 1
cursh> echo 2
cursh> }
1
2
```

Comment: Oh that's really handy!

Comment: Provided of course, that the shell option `HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` has been set before: `setopt HIST_IGNORE_SPACE` or just `setopt -g`.

Comment: I'm assuming it is, since the OP indicates his understanding of the option in the question.